# Why EF doesnt update navigation property

Tags: entity-framework

I use Code First EF 5.0 on >Net 4.0 and I has 2 class:

```
public partial class Kennel
{
    public Kennel()
    {
        this.Brands = new List<Brand>();
        this.Dogs = new List<Dog>();
        this.Breeds = new List<Breed>();
        this.Owners = new List<Person>();
        this.Name1 = new KennelName();
        this.Name2 = new KennelName();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public /*DogClub*/int Type { get; set; }
    public KennelName Name1 { get; set; }
    public KennelName Name2 { get; set; }
    public string CertificateNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? AssigmentDate { get; set; }
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public int? FederationID { get; set; }
    public int? MainOwnerID { get; set; }
    public int? MainBreedID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public virtual Breed MainBreed { get; set; }
    public virtual Federation Federation { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Person MainOwner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Breed> Breeds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Owners { get; set; }
}

public partial class Breed
{
    public Breed()
    {
        this.Dogs = new List<Dog>();
        this.ExpertKerungs = new List<ExpertKerung>();
        this.Hallmarks = new List<Hallmark>();
        this.Colors = new List<Color>();
        this.ExpertBreeds = new List<ExpertBreed>();
        this.Kennels = new List<Kennel>();
        this.MainKennels = new List<Kennel>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FciNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BreedGroupID { get; set; }
    public bool IsKerung { get; set; }
    public string NameLat { get; set; }
    public string NativeName { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? StandardDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCACIB { get; set; }
    public bool IsWork { get; set; }

    public virtual BreedGroup BreedGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExpertKerung> ExpertKerungs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hallmark> Hallmarks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExpertBreed> ExpertBreeds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Kennel> Kennels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Kennel> MainKennels { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping:

```
public class KennelMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Kennel>
{
    public KennelMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties
        //this.Property(t => t.Name1.Name)
        //    .IsRequired();

        //this.Property(t => t.Name1.IntlName)
        //    .IsRequired();

        //this.Property(t => t.Name2.Name)
        //    .IsRequired();

        //this.Property(t => t.Name2.IntlName)
        //    .IsRequired();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Kennels");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("Type");
        this.Property(t => t.Name1.Name).HasColumnName("Name1_Name");
        this.Property(t => t.Name1.IntlName).HasColumnName("Name1_IntlName");
        this.Property(t => t.Name1.Type).HasColumnName("Name1_Type");
        this.Property(t => t.Name1.Approved).HasColumnName("Name1_Approved");
        this.Property(t => t.Name2.Name).HasColumnName("Name2_Name");
        this.Property(t => t.Name2.IntlName).HasColumnName("Name2_IntlName");
        this.Property(t => t.Name2.Type).HasColumnName("Name2_Type");
        this.Property(t => t.Name2.Approved).HasColumnName("Name2_Approved");
        this.Property(t => t.CertificateNumber).HasColumnName("CertificateNumber");
        this.Property(t => t.AssigmentDate).HasColumnName("AssigmentDate");
        this.Property(t => t.Folder).HasColumnName("Folder");
        this.Property(t => t.Comment).HasColumnName("Comment");
        this.Property(t => t.StatusID).HasColumnName("StatusID");
        this.Property(t => t.FederationID).HasColumnName("FederationID");
        this.Property(t => t.MainOwnerID).HasColumnName("MainOwnerID");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.Owners)
                .WithMany(t => t.Kennels)
                .Map(m =>
                        {
                            m.ToTable("OwnerKennel");
                            m.MapLeftKey("Kennels_ID");
                            m.MapRightKey("Owners_ID");
                        });

        this.HasOptional(t => t.MainBreed)
                .WithMany(t => t.MainKennels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MainBreedID);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Federation)
                .WithMany(t => t.Kennels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FederationID);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Status)
                .WithMany(t => t.Kennels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StatusID);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.MainOwner)
                .WithMany(t => t.MainKennels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MainOwnerID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

If I write next code:

```
  int breedID = 1; // some value  
  Breed br = _kennel.Breeds.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == breedID);  
  if (br != null)  
  {  
    _kennel.MainBreed = br;  
    // but: _kennel.MainBreedID != br.ID  
  }
```

OR:

```
  int breedID = 1; // some value  
  Breed br = _kennel.Breeds.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == breedID);  
  if (br != null)  
  {  
    _kennel.MainBreedID = breedID;  
    // but: _kennel.MainBreed != br  
  }
```

Why EF doesnt update navigation property? I set ProxyCreationEnabled and AutoDetectChangesEnabled, but this not work.

See another example of sample code (it accurately reflects my real application code):

```
Kennel kennel = ctx.Kennels.Add(ctx.Kennels.Create());
kennel.Name1.Name = "Test Kennel";
List<Breed> breeds = ctx.Breeds.Include(b => b.BreedGroup).OrderBy(t => t.BreedGroupID).Where(t => t.ID == 755 || t.ID == 772).ToList();
foreach (var b in breeds)
  kennel.Breeds.Add(b);
if (breeds.Count > 0)
{
  kennel.MainBreed = breeds[0];
  foreach (var k in kennel.MainBreed.MainKennels)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MainKennel: " + k.Name1.Name);
  ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
  //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MainBreed: " + kennel.MainBreed);
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MainBreedID: " + kennel.MainBreedID);
}
```

After call to DetectChanges all navigation properties and collection reflect changes (kennel.MainBreedID != null).

Comment: What are you exppecting to happen that isn't?

Comment: I am expect, if I set _kennel.MainBreedID to breedID than navigation property updated automaticaly: _kennel.MainBreed == breed and in the collection breed.MainKennels will popup the breed (without explicit call to context.DetectChanges()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making all your POCO properties virtual rather than just the navigation properties.  This will allow EF to create [change tracking proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456848%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) rather than lazy loading proxies.  *I've not tested this,* but you may then get the behavior that you expect.

Comment: All navigation properties are virtual: public virtual Breed MainBreed { get; set; } - for example. I tried to write public virtual int? MainBreedID { get; set; }, but without any effect.

Comment: Try making *all* properties virtual.  This enables another kind of proxy object.

Comment: Thank you, after set all properties to virtual all work without call to DetectChanges. Why this info no on Miscrosoft site about EF5.0?

Comment: Some of the EF documentation is sparse.  There is one useful link that explains the requirements for the various kinds of proxy - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx - but it doesn't spell out what you need to do for your scenario.

Comment: @AlexanderElistratov: Please accept this answer because it solved your problem: Click on the white check mark left from the answer and turn it into green.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the intialisation of the collections from the constructor

```
//this.Dogs = new List<Dog>();
//this.ExpertKerungs = new List<ExpertKerung>();
//this.Hallmarks = new List<Hallmark>();
//this.Colors = new List<Color>();
//this.ExpertBreeds = new List<ExpertBreed>();
//this.Kennels = new List<Kennel>();
//this.MainKennels = new List<Kennel>();
```

Comment: If I comment this lines than I get exception NullReferenceException when I add breed to kennel collection: kennel.Breeds.Add(breed) -> Kennel.Breeds is NULL. In this case all collection are NULL.

Comment: There must be a problem with the lazy loading proxies - i.e. they're not being generated.

Comment: No, if I watch in debuger I see that breed type is {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Breed_72DF71D740DF290F1FEBC8F98EB0F94B65972B0F2DD559AF5514E6F51240F19F} - it's proxy...